# How can I get parameter from the URL in Websphere commerce CmdImpl class

Tags: websphere-commerce

Is there any way to get url parameter in websphere commerce CmdImpl class.
I am trying like this

```
    SmartDataBeanImpl bean = new SmartDataBeanImpl();
    HttpServletRequest request = bean.getHttpRequest();
    String currencyId = request.getParameter("currencyId");
```

But I got the NullPointer exception at 3rd Line

Comment: I have solve this 1 hour ago.

Answer (score 2):

Given the assumption that you are working with a controller command then you should access the URL parameters like this:

```
public void setRequestProperties(TypedProperty pRequestProperties)  {
    String currencyId = pRequestProperties.getString("currencyId", ""); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
requestProperties.getString("URL", null)
```

You would see this in most of the OOB controller commands  in the validateParameters() method.